# Element to bottom of the page in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem positioning a footer ul list at the bottom of my boostrap xs-4 column on a test website I'm building at http://www.badalic.com/burja.html For some reason the row class does not seem to fill the 100% height of my website. If I try to position the footer to top:0 it works flawlesly, but I can't figure out why it won't do the same for bottom aswell. Any help is well appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your row class fills more than 100% of the height. button element in the xs-4 column is the problem

```
.button {
    margin-top:45px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Both the columns have a difference of 20px. xs-4 column occupies more space vertically..

change button class property to see the difference.

```
.button {
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your row is filling 100% of the website, but your footer is positioned absolutely at the bottom of the window.

To get your footer to sit below your row remove the `bottom: 0` and `position: absolute` from your css.